# Why I get Undefined email data result from findAll Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Please help, how to show email from Sequelize findAll query, because i get Undefined from my source code, can some body help me ?
Here my code

```
testdata.get = (req, res) => {
  User.findAll()
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.email);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({
        message: (err, "Error")
      });
    });
  return;
};
```

My result on terminal like this

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `email`, `password`, `level`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User`;
undefined
```

There's my screenshoot
[image: Undefined]

Comment: Log what `data` is instead. It's not an object containing `email`

Comment: Data is an array of objects... do `console.log(data[0].email)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `.findAll()` method returns an array, not a single object which you can access by the dot notation `.email`. Refer to [`.findAll()` docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#-findall-search-for-multiple-elements-in-the-database).

```
testdata.get = (req, res) => {
  User.findAll()
    .then(data => {

        data.forEach((object) => console.log(object.email));

    })
    .catch(err => {
       res.json({
       message: (err, "Error")
    });
  });
  return;
};
```

Comment: Thank u :) for helping

Answer (score 1):

I think the data will be an array of objects and not just an object.

So I suggest you log data first and then loop through that and check if it contains the email key.

Comment: Thank u :) for helping